# different convergence of the series $\sum_1^\infty{(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the series
$$\sum_1^\infty{(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}}$$
Pick out the true statements:
(a) The series converges for all real values of $x$.
(b) The series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.
(c) The series does not converge absolutely for any real value of $x$.

---

(a) is true by alternating series test.
(c) is not true as $\sum_1^\infty{\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}} \ge \sum_1^\infty{\frac{1}{n}}$.
(b) I have no idea.
seek your help for (b)

Comment: I do not understand your phrasing. Are you saying that (c) is not true?

Answer (score 1):

Your sum can be written like this
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^n\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}}=x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n}{n^2}=x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}
$$
both series are know to converge. In particular (as a reference) you have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}=-\ln 2
$$
and
$$
x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{n^2}=-x^2\frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$
and what you write in (c) is right but is not your original sum, since you forgot the $(-1)^n$. This is a fundamental part of the sum!

Comment: You only prove the point wise convergence.  how about the uniformly convergence?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Decompose the general term as the sum of two alternating series. You should be able to prove that each of them is convergent (each of the sum has a perfectly known value). From there, the remaining is simple.

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: can we write it as sum of two series irrespective of its convergence :O ??

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik. I suppose that if you prove that each series is convergent, thei sum is convergent. Don't you agree ?

Comment: I am not authorized to confirm anything as i am just a beginner.. I feel what you said is true but i am confused....

Comment: How to prove the given series is not uniformly convergent. I tried to apply M-Test. It is not helpful. Can you provide a hint?

Answer (score -2):

(c) is surly not true
because the left hand side Phrase is a adition of The two series converge but the right hand side phrase is not converge